# Pandas groupby with no function and display each unique value only once

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm not sure Pandas does this or not.

Given a dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

I want to group by `Id` and then list sorted by descending order on `Score`, like this:

```
Id        Name              Score   Index
-------------------------------------------
123       John Smith        1.0     AM
          Johnny Smith      0.92    PP
345       John Smith        1.0     WL
789       John Smith        1.0     WL
          Jonathan Smith    0.91    PP
011       Jon Smithson      0.80    AM
012       Jon Smythe        0.77    WL
```

One of the main requirements here is that we only want each distinct `Id` to be displayed one time.  If there is a way to accomplish this but the format is not exactly like the above, but conveys the same message, that's ok.  Note that there is no function to be applied to any column (mean, sum, etc.).

Here is the code to reproduce the Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

arrays = [['123', '345', '789', '123', '789', '011','012'],
        ['John Smith', 'John Smith', 'John Smith', 'Johnny Smith', 'Jonathan Smith', 'Jon Smithson', 'John Smythe'],
          [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.92, 0.91, 0.80, 0.77],
          ['AM', 'WL','WL', 'PP', 'PP', 'AM', 'WL']]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=('Id', 'Name', 'Score', 'Index'))
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index)
df
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```py
df = df.sort_values('Id').set_index(['Id', 'Name'])
```

```py
>>> print(df)
                    Score Index
Id  Name                       
11  Jon-Smithson     0.80    AM
12  Jon-Smythe       0.77    WL
123 John-Smith       1.00    AM
    Johnny-Smith     0.92    PP
345 John-Smith       1.00    WL
789 Jonathan-Smith   0.91    PP
    John-Smith       1.00    WL
```

Or this:

```py
df = df.sort_values('Id').set_index('Id')
```

```py
>>> print(df)
               Name  Score Index
Id                              
11     Jon-Smithson   0.80    AM
12       Jon-Smythe   0.77    WL
123      John-Smith   1.00    AM
123    Johnny-Smith   0.92    PP
345      John-Smith   1.00    WL
789  Jonathan-Smith   0.91    PP
789      John-Smith   1.00    WL
```

If the `Id` column is numeric (of dtype `int`) and you want it to be zero-padded, you can do the following, and then use one of the above solutions, substituting `new_df` for `df`:

```py
i = df['Id'].astype(str)
i = i.str.rjust(i.str.len().max(), '0')
new_df = df.copy()
new_df['Id'] = i
```

e.g.

```py
>>> new_df = new_df.sort_values('Id').set_index(['Id', 'Name'])
>>> print(new_df)
                    Score Index
Id  Name                       
011 Jon-Smithson     0.80    AM
012 Jon-Smythe       0.77    WL
123 John-Smith       1.00    AM
    Johnny-Smith     0.92    PP
345 John-Smith       1.00    WL
789 Jonathan-Smith   0.91    PP
    John-Smith       1.00    WL
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the sorting you want, @Stpete111. Note you can change `sort_values('Id')` to `sort_values(['Id', ...])` where `...` is any number of the other columns in the dataframe. You can also pass `ascending=False` to sort in descending order, e.g. `sort_values(['Id', ...], ascending=False)`.

Comment: when I run just your first suggestion I get the error `KeyError: "None of ['Id', 'Name'] are in the columns"`. Any ideas why?   I run exactly my code from my post, then your `df = df.sort_values('Id').set_index(['Id', 'Name'])`, and I get that error.  FYI - my Id column is string format.

Comment: I'm on Python 3.10 and Pandas 1.3.4.  Maybe different version from you?

Comment: Ok so I was able to achieve your first results set with only `df = df.sort_values('Id')`. Can you tell me a little more about what your thoughts are behind using `set_index`?

Comment: I used `set_index` because you emphasized having only one of each ID displayed - with `pd.MultiIndex`, which `.set_index([...])` does for you, it does exactly that.

Comment: Haha, I'm using the same Python and pandas versions. I guess we like to be up-to-date!

Comment: My only guess as to why the `set_index` is not working for you is that your columns are not named the same as mine. Even whitespace or case differences matter. Try `print(df.columns)` and make sure they look okay.

Comment: Column names are definitely the same. So if you copy/paste exactly my Dataframe code from my post, then add `df = df.sort_values('Id').set_index(['Id', 'Name'])` and run it, you don't get an error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239369/discussion-between-user17242583-and-stpete111).